# How to make method wait for a response in order to return a value?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am sure this has been asked before, but I don't know the keywords to search for it.

Suppose that I have a function `validateConnection` that returns a `bool`. This function makes a call to the server (using anetworking) and returns `true` if the request was successful (this is just a example).

I want my method to wait until the response is back in order to return the `bool`: how to achieve that?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can use completion handler. where you get response  create a completeion handler which will trigger when your request is completed.

Comment: exactly, if you look at the correct answer you find it was using blocks. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Called `Block` you can learn more about block by [Introduction to Objective-C Blocks](http://www.appcoda.com/objective-c-blocks-tutorial/)

Following is the sample method to create block and its call back:

```
-(void)callmethodwith:(NSString*)string withCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL success, NSError* error, id responce))completion
{

    NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MY FUNTn CALLBACK %@",string];
    if (completion){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completion(YES,nil,str); // here that call when method complete
        });
    }
}
```

And you can call it like following:

```
[self callmethodwith:@"My new" withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error, id responce) {
        if(success)
        {
            NSLog(@"==%@",responce); // here you get response once method camplet
        }
    }];
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Wonder why have people upvoted the UI Blocking vague answer instead.

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

I think, once the method is executing then there is no way of stopping it.

But you can cancel if it is not fired.

Like following way;

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(yourMethod) object:nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

Comment: This is good but the one marked as correct was better. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use AFNetworking success and failure methods to wait for response. Alternatively, you can use `performSelectorOnMainThread` method

```
[yourViewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(yourFunction:) withObject:nil
waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: synchronous request will freeze the UI it is not recommended.

Comment: waiting can be done by showing activity indicator or allowing user to access the screen for some other work till the response is awaited but freezing UI will misguide the user that app is hanged and he will go for killing the app.

Comment: block is a right way to doing that type of task check my answer for more info

Answer (score -1):

While working with blocks or Completion Handler, make sure you are not using a strong reference of your class or any view, as it affects retain count.

While working with blocks or completion handler use weak reference inside block, something like this,

```
__weak Class *weakSelf = self;
[manager communicateUsingGETMethod:@"www.google.com" parameterDictionary:@{} success:^(id successDicitoanary) {
    // Call using weak reference.
[weakSelf handleSuccess];
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    [weakSelf handleFailure];
}];
```

and write whole code separately.This will make code more readable and you will get rid of retain cycle too as you are calling your completionCode with weak reference,

For your reference, read apple doc for [Avoid Strong Reference Cycles when Capturing self](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)